# RXJS operator to trigger timer observable immdiately before its end time is reached

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

I am using `RXJS` in an angular app with `ngrx` for state management.

I have a `timer` observable with a 3s time delay. It runs once. It also has a `takeUntil` to stop the timer based on an Event.

My question is, if there is any kind of RXJS operator or something that can be used to trigger the timer before its end time is reached?

Its something like a time bomb with a predefined timer, but also has a detonator handle so that it can be set-off immediately by using that trigger before the actual end time is reached.

I am not that much knowledgeable of rxjs so pardon if the question is silly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`race`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/race) operator.

```js
race(of('DETONATED!').pipe(delay(3000)), fromEvent(document.querySelector('button'), 'click').pipe(map(() => 'DETONATED!'))).subscribe(console.log);
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-q1bs8g?file=index.ts)